# Sign up using Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, backbone.js, underscore.js

I want to use this backbone validation http://jsfiddle.net/thedersen/udXL5/ in my project but when I install backbone.js, jquery and underscore.js to my files and when i try to run it on my computer I got 
    1. Cannot read property 'callbacks' of undefined ?

```
I have installed backbone.js and underscore.js and I have placed the backbone code in script.js file where I can easily maintaining it.

Thanks for the help.
```

Comment: You need to show us the script.js

Comment: Hey sorry it is the same code from this application I just placed it in new file called script.js.
Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/u3ejnon8/